# Как вывести значение стоимости монеты

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
a = cg.get_price(ids='litecoin', vs_currencies='rub')
#{'litecoin': {'rub': 4451.29}}
print(a)
```

Как вывести из (#{'litecoin': {'rub': 4451.29}}) - только стоимость?

Comment: `print(a['litecoin']['rub'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так:

```
print(a['litecoin']['rub'])
```

Этот код выведет:

```
4451.29
```

Ещё можно так:

```
for valuta in a:
    print(valuta + ':', a[valuta])
```

Этот код выведет:

```
rub : 4451.29
```